# Find fields with empty strings

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to find fields with empty strings. They look like this:

[image]

Python code:

```
from loguru import logger
from google.cloud import firestore

firestore_client = firestore.Client.from_service_account_json('creds.json')
ref = firestore_client.collection('database')
users_ref = ref.collection(u'users').where(u'placeName', u'==', u'')
docs = [snapshot for snapshot in users_ref.stream()]
```

My code is not working. How can I get such fields?

Comment: Can you give some more info? What type is users_ref.stream()? Is it a list of dicts?

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "not working". See the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), 
and provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just use conditional statement like:

```
if(<string> == ""):
    statement
```

this will carry out your statements you want to do in these empty strings